# Is it possible to have stricter type checking on union types?

Tags: typescript

In accordance with the [specification section 3.4](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf), this does not compile:

```
let s: string | number;
s = false; // not a string or a number
```

So, logically, given classes A, B and C, I would also expect this not to compile, but it does:

```
let a: A | B;
a = new C();
a = "hi";
a = {}; // a can be anything!
```

Is there some workaround to get stricter type checking here? Also, is this a bug or by design? If it's by design, I really don't understand this design choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't give definitions for `A`, `B`, or `C`, but I can infer what they were:

```
class A {}
class B {}
class C {}
let a: A | B;
a = new C();
a = "hi";
a = {}; // a can be anything!
```

TypeScript uses a structural type system ([read the FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely)) and these empty classes are interchangeable.
From the FAQ:

> Types with no members can be substituted by any type. 
>   In general, you should never find yourself declaring an interface with no properties.

However, if you add members to your classes, like you would in real life, you do get errors:

```
class A { a: number }
class B { b: string }
class C { c: boolean }
let a: A | B;
a = new C(); // error
a = "hi"; // error
a = {}; // error
```

Comment: So why is `a` assignable to a string? Surely a string doesn't have the same members as an empty class?

Comment: `a` isn't assignable to string. Try it. Maybe you meant "why is string assignable to (the empty type) A ?", in which case the answer is answered in the FAQ: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-all-types-assignable-to-empty-interfaces

Comment: Yeah that was backwards. So if you want something like a marker interface or class in TypeScript you have to add some dummy field to it, or is there a better way?

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh I added some text from the FAQ, feel free to rollback my edit if you like.